# Call WCF Synchronously from Windows Phone8

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Some of my calls take a longer time on windows phone 8. calling them Asynchronous is causing trouble for me.

Can i call WCF service methods synchronously sometimes?
any way for this? 
an urgent response is needed
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All calls out to the web have to be done asynchronously.  The synchronous versions of those methods don't even exist in the SDK.

What kind of trouble are you seeing?  Even if your calls were synchronous, it wouldn't make them return any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use extension methods and TPL async.

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthiasshapiro/archive/2012/12/10/window-8-win-phone-code-sharing-httpwebrequest-getresponseasync.aspx).

Example:

```
public async Task<string> GetMyData(string urlToCall)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToCall);
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Extension method:

```
 public static class HttpExtensions
    {
        public static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            var taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();
            request.BeginGetResponse(asyncResponse =>
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest responseRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResponse.AsyncState;
                    HttpWebResponse someResponse = (HttpWebResponse)responseRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResponse);
                    taskComplete.TrySetResult(someResponse);
                }
                catch (WebException webExc)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse failedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webExc.Response;
                    taskComplete.TrySetResult(failedResponse);
                }
            }, request);
            return taskComplete.Task;
        }
     }
```

Comment: This would not make the call synchronous, it would just allow the method be written AS THOUGH it were synchronous.

Comment: True but it allows one to call multiple methods synchronously or makes it easier to do that, instead of nested callbacks.  That's what I thought was meant by "Can i call WCF service methods synchronously sometimes"